# React, slow rendering for last element in array

Tags: reactjs, performance, render

So I have a problem where I store image paths in an array (size 5), when clicking on a button, it renders immediately the right image but when clicking at the last button it takes time to render its image or does not even render, the state is stored at the parent component so I wonder why it takes time to render, and when I tried on a bigger array(size 6), the image renders fast for the index 4 and renders really slow or not even for the last index

here is my code

```js
      const Option2DropDown = () => {
        useEffect(() => {
          if (choices.length === 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              choices.push(null);
            }
          }
        }, [choices]);
    
        return (
          <Row>
            {choices.map((abox, idx) => {
              return (
                <OptionDropDown
                  key={idx.toString()}
                  id={idx.toString()}
                  img={cards[idx]}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Row>
        );
      };

      const OptionDropDown = (props) => {
            return (
            <Col >
              <DropdownButton
                onMouseOver={(e) => handleChoiceButton(e, props.id)}
                title={
                  <img
                    width={80}
                    height={80}
                    src={props.img}
                    className="selectHandBtn"
                  />
                }
                disabled={choiceConfirmed}
                drop={"end"}
              >
                    <Dropdown.Item id={Hands.rock} className="selectHandBtn" as="button" onClick={selectHand}>
                        <img id={Hands.rock} width={80} height={80} src={rock} />
                    </Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item id={Hands.paper} className="selectHandBtn" as="button" onClick={selectHand}>
                        <img id={Hands.paper} width={80} height={80} src={paper} />
                    </Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item id={Hands.paper} className="selectHandBtn" as="button" onClick={selectHand}>
                        <img  id={Hands.scissor} width={80} height={80} src={scissor}/>
                    </Dropdown.Item>
              </DropdownButton>
            </Col>
          );
  };
```

that function generates something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg3ma.png), only last one takes times to render the right image

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please include your code so we can better understand the issue?

Comment: What do "slow rendering" "renders really slow or not even" mean? The image takes a long time to load? Is the image larger than the others? After clicking, there's a delay in something (what?) happening? It also seems like you're doing something wrong with `choices` by pushing to it rather than using state. If you can make a full reproducible codesandbox that would help, right now there's no way to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be an off-by-one error. The loop in your useEffect will iterate 4 times, and on the fifth it will shortcircuit as i is not less than 5.

If the useEffect is not necessary, I think you can achieve the same functionality by removing it and simply mapping cards instead:

```
{cards.map((card, idx) => {
              return (
                <OptionDropDown
                  key={idx.toString()}
                  id={idx.toString()}
                  img={card}
                />
              );
            })}
```

Comment: that one fixed the "slow" rendering thank you!